# Jquery remove/add CSS class

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

There are 5 tiles if i click on one of them it opens them (width 100%) and when i click the X on the top right it close it that works fine. but when it is opened and i click the blue box again it will override the global vars and the onclick Close dose not know the old position anymore.

Fiddle Here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/16/)

HTML

```
<div class="tile" id="tp1">
    <img class="bus" src="http://s14.directupload.net/images/131130/4gzq9oaz.png" />
    <div class="close">x</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tile, .tile_open {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#0090db;
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////
        Tile Width And Location eddid here
///////////////////////////////////////*/
#tp1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;       
}
/*//////////////////////////////////////
                IMG SIZE
///////////////////////////////////////*/
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////
           Close Button
///////////////////////////////////////*/
.close {
    display: none;
    background-color:#C85051;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.open .close {
    display: block;
}
```

Jquery

```
var posL , posT;

$(".tile").on("click", function (e) { 
    var pos= $(this).position();
         posL = $(this).css('left'),
         posT = $(this).css('top');

    e.stopPropagation();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
        $(this).animate({
            "top": pos.top - pos.top,
            "left":pos.left - pos.left,
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        }, 1000).addClass('open')
        $(this).removeClass('tile').addClass('tile_open'); //<-- This was my try to get it to work
    }


});



$(".close").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        "left" : posL,
        "top" : posT,
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "50px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('open')
    $(this).removeClass('tile_open').addClass('tile');//<-- This was my try to get it to work

});
```

Comment: Sry forgot the fiddle i included it now.

Comment: so you want that>> when clicking X, it must return to same place?

Comment: Yes its doing this already. the problem is when you click the Opend blue box again it dose not go to the original position

Comment: So click a blue box with a bus. then it opens. then click the opend think again. then close it with the X then there is the bug hope you understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of your script is that when you click the blue img it sets the original position and that's fine.

**BUT** If you click it again when it's big, it sets it again and **THAT'S WRONG.**

That's wrong because you store the position in those vars **BEFORE** you check if the div is actually already full screen or not

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/18/)

So you have to change this:

```
$(".tile").on("click", function (e) { 
var pos= $(this).position();
     posL = $(this).css('left'),
     posT = $(this).css('top');

e.stopPropagation();
if(!$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
```

to this

```
$(".tile").on("click", function (e) { 
e.stopPropagation();
if(!$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
    var pos= $(this).position();
     posL = $(this).css('left'),
     posT = $(this).css('top');
```

And it's only the main problem. You also need to increase the element `z-index` when it gets full page and decrease it when it goes to the original state, or it'll stay under the other blue divs. Check my demo. In my demo i also put `margin:0` to the body ( just to be more precise in the animation ) and used this

```
var pos= $(this).offset();
     posL = pos.left,
     posT = pos.top;
```

instead of this

```
var pos= $(this).position();
     posL = $(this).css('left'),
     posT = $(this).css('top');
```

Just to be more precise again. ( I don't know the full structure of your page and `offset` it's better because [**offset**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) the position of the element relatively to the document )

Comment: Thanks works perfekt you even fixed a bug i did not ask for. Thanks for your work

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is scope.  When you click the first picture, it opens and stores the x, y, but when you click the next picture, it overwrites the previous x, y coordinates so you need to change the scope of your values.

Here's an example of your JS properly scoped.
http://jsfiddle.net/Nemesis02/2Zx3m/23/

```
$(".tile").on("click", function (e) { 
    var pos= $(this).position(),
        posL = $(this).css('left'), posT = $(this).css('top');

    var closeFunction = function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({
            "left" : posL,
            "top" : posT,
            "width": "100px",
            "height": "50px"
        }, 1000).removeClass('open')
        $(this).removeClass('tile_open').addClass('tile');//<-- This was my try to get it to work
        $(this).unbind('close', closeFunction)
    };

    e.stopPropagation();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
        $(this).animate({
            "top": pos.top - pos.top,
            "left":pos.left - pos.left,
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        }, 1000).addClass('open')
        $(this).removeClass('tile').addClass('tile_open'); //<-- This was my try to get it to work
        $(this).find(".close").on("click", closeFunction);
    }


});
```

Comment: thanks this works perfektly fine i did not accept your becouse the other guy fixed another bug but iwill mark that as a useful answer

Answer (score 1):

In your example it is needed to do the following,

1.restore the class name value by properly removing `tile_open`

2.use `offset()` function to retrieve the top position

http://jsfiddle.net/2jnM2/

```
var posL , posT;

$(".tile").on("click", function (e) { 
    var pos= $(this).position();
         posL = $(this).css('left'),
         //posT = $(this).css('top');
             posT = $(this).offset().top;

    e.stopPropagation();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('open') ) {
        $(this).animate({
            "top": pos.top - pos.top,
            "left":pos.left - pos.left,
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        }, 1000).addClass('open')
        $(this).removeClass('tile').addClass('tile_open'); //<-- This was my try to get it to work
    }


});



$(".close").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        "left" : posL,
        "top" : posT,
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "50px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('open').removeClass('tile_open').addClass('tile');//<-- This was my try to get it to work

});
```

Comment: this dose not work for me maybe you did not understod what i meant

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the position data on each image and then retrieve it from that image later:

```
    $(".tile").on("click", function (e) { 
    var $this = $(this),
        pos = $this.position();

    $this.data({
        posL: $this.css('left'),
        posT: $this.css('top')
    });

    e.stopPropagation();
    if(!$this.hasClass('open') ) {
        $this.animate({
            "top": pos.top - pos.top,
            "left":pos.left - pos.left,
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%"
        }, 1000).addClass('open')

    }

});



$(".close").on("click", function (e) {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $parent.stop().animate({
        "left" : $parent.data('posL'),
        "top" : $parent.data('posT'),
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "50px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('open');


});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/25/)